# Set a dummy variable in an R data frame for plotting by group in ggplot2

Tags: r, pattern-matching, ggplot2, dataframe

I have a data frame in R, and I'd like to add dummy variables in order to plot different items different colors.

My data frame, `df <-`, is something like this:

```
UID CategoryA  count
  1       AAA      2
  2       AAA      2
  3       BBB      1
  4       CCC      1
  5       DDD      1
```

I have another list, `special <- c("AAA", "DDD")`

I'd like to end up with `df` something like:

```
UID CategoryA  count dummy
  1       AAA      2     1
  2       AAA      2     1
  3       BBB      1     0
  4       CCC      1     0
  5       DDD      1     1
```

So that `dummy = 1`, wherever `CategoryA == special`

I tried searching for this, but I suspect it requires `%in%` which is hard to google for.

I may be doing this for misguided reasons, so maybe you can help me short-circuit the problem---my objective in creating this dummy variable is to create a bar graph that's sort of a sideways histogram listing all the categories by count.  I want this variable to provide a `group` in order to color the ones where dummy==1 red and the ones where dummy==0 green.  I'll be using ggplot2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, just after posting, I figured this out from someone answering an earlier question of mine...

```
df$dummy <- ifelse(df$categoryA %in% special,1,0)
```

For completeness, I also had to add this to my ggplot code...

```
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00FFAA","#FF0000"), 
                       name="Legend",
                       breaks=c("TRUE", "FALSE"),
                       labels=c("Dummy", "No Dummy")) +
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are some possible constructions:

```
categoryA <- c("AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD")
special <- c("AAA", "DDD")

# Create a dummy variable
as.integer(categoryA %in% special)
# [1] 1 1 0 0 1

# Create a color vector (2 methods shown)
c("green", "red")[categoryA %in% special + 1]
# [1] "red"   "red"   "green" "green" "red"  
ifelse(categoryA %in% special, "red", "green")
# [1] "red"   "red"   "green" "green" "red"
```